# How to implement UserControl in WinRT

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, overriding, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have created a simple `UserControl` consisting solely of a `Grid` and an embraced `Image`.

Now I want to apply events such as "ManipulationDeltaEvent", etc. for touch-control. When I assign an event-handler like

```
pic->ActionToken = pic->ManipulationDelta +=
ref new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(this, &MainPage::SwipeImageEventHandler);

pic->CompletedToken = pic->ManipulationCompleted +=
ref new ManipulationCompletedEventHandler(this, &MainPage::ImageManipulationCompletedEventHandler);
```

I receive valid `EventRegistrationToken`s, but when I want to swipe over the control, simply nothing happens (I debugged).

I read about `overriding` the `OnManipulationDelta`-method from `Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Control`, but I here I am stuck:

```
protected:

void OnManipulationDelta
(Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs^ e) override {

}
```

---

Although only barely related, for `C++\CLI` it states on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onmanipulationdelta.aspx):

The `OnManipulationDelta` method has no default implementation. Override OnManipulationDelta in a derived class to handle the ManipulationDelta event. Be sure to call the OnManipulationDelta method of the base class so that base classes receive the event.

---

Please give me a hint, thank you.

**EDIT**

The overriding is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify ManipulationMode on the control and the control needs a non-null Background or Fill, e.g. Background="Transparent".

Comment: Thank you very much. I shouldn't be doing such stuff late at night.